# AnpointStudio deploy issue

Tags: mule-studio

I am trying to run a project in Anypointstudio 7.3.2, but i am getting the following error when deploying the project:

Caused by: org.mule.runtime.core.api.config.ConfigurationException: Couldn't read from file log4j2.yaml
Caused by: org.mule.runtime.config.internal.dsl.model.config.ConfigurationPropertiesException: Couldn't read from file log4j2.yaml
Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerException: mapping values are not allowed here
 in 'reader', line 14, column 56:
     ... out pattern="%-5p %d [%t] [event: %X{correlationId}] %c: %m%n" />

Any help with what could be wrong and what the solution is? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use YAML configuration (log4j2.yaml) but the contents of the file are actually an XML log4j2 configuration? That will not work. You will need to convert it to YAML.